# Element in a resource dictionary is already the child of another element?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

In a UWP app targeting 10240; I know when you try to add an element that is already painted in the UI You receive:

> Element is already the child of another element.'

However I have a border in the resources of the page, add it by code, and receive the same exception.

```
<Page
x:Class="App13.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red" x:Name="Border" x:Key="Border" />        
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Height="100" Width="100" Content="Add" Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
</Grid>
```

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace App13
{ 
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage() => InitializeComponent();

        private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var border = Resources["Border"] as Border;
            if (!(Content is Panel panel)) return;

            panel.Children.Add(border);
        }
    }
}
```

If the element is in the resource dictionary, and not yet rendered, how can it be it's the child of another element?

Comment: The exception doesn't show much. Only that exception.And I checked the children of the parent where I'm adding the border, and there is nothing but the button triggering the tapped event

Comment: I checked and the Parent is set to null in the border object

Comment: This is a small example. In reallity I have some usercontrols with x:bind in the resource dictionary. I have a very specific problem and this can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Element is already the child of another element.'

Each UI element in UWP can only be used in the UI in one place at one time. The instance will be generated when the resource is loaded. So, You could not add them to the panel any more. However, you could create a deep copy via the follow `UIElementExtensions`, and add the copy to the panel.

```
public static class UIElementExtensions
{
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T source) where T : UIElement
    {

        T result;

        // Get the type
        Type type = source.GetType();

        // Create an instance
        result = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as T;

        CopyProperties<T>(source, result, type);

        DeepCopyChildren<T>(source, result);

        return result;
    }
    private static void DeepCopyChildren<T>(T source, T result) where T : UIElement
    {
        // Deep copy children.
        Panel sourcePanel = source as Panel;
        if (sourcePanel != null)
        {
            Panel resultPanel = result as Panel;
            if (resultPanel != null)
            {
                foreach (UIElement child in sourcePanel.Children)
                {
                    // RECURSION!
                    UIElement childClone = DeepClone(child);
                    resultPanel.Children.Add(childClone);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static void CopyProperties<T>(T source, T result, Type type) where T : UIElement
    {
        // Copy all properties.

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = type.GetRuntimeProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Name != "Name") 
            {
                if ((property.CanWrite) && (property.CanRead))
                {
                    object sourceProperty = property.GetValue(source);

                    UIElement element = sourceProperty as UIElement;
                    if (element != null)
                    {
                        UIElement propertyClone = element.DeepClone();

                        property.SetValue(result, propertyClone);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            property.SetValue(result, sourceProperty);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var border = Resources["Border"] as Border;
    if (!(Content is Panel panel)) return;
    var NewBorder = border.DeepClone<Border>();
    panel.Children.Add(NewBorder);

}
```

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for the answer but I the resources inside the resource dictionary are not rendered, I thought that exception only happened when you tried to add an element that was already in the UI Tree.